# using accumulator-rule to remember context info

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

Short question:

why my `xsl:accumulator-rule`
 `<xsl:when test="substring($msg, $value, string-length(./TagField/@value)) != ./TagField/@value">` doesn't work with Saxon PE 9.9, but works with XSL Professional 2020 sp1. The error reported by Saxon is:

> Error evaluating (fn:accumulator-before(...) =
>   fn:accumulator-after(...)) in xsl:when/@test on line 45 column 100 of
>   format.xslt:   XPTY0004: An empty sequence is not allowed as the
>   second argument of fn:substring(). Found   while atomizing the first
>   operand of '='   In template rule with match="pattern matching
>   node()/element(Q{}MessageFormat)/element(Q{}StructFormat)[(not(attribute::attribute(Q{}repeat)))
>   and child::element(Q{}TagField)]" on line 82 of format.xslt
>        invoked by built-in template rule (shallow-copy)
>        invoked by xsl:apply-templates at file:/D:/issue/pfr-transportevent-v01/config/transformation/xslt/format.xslt#102
>   at procedure complete-struct on line 101 of format.xslt:
>        invoked by global xsl:variable   In template rule with match="/" on line 104 of format.xslt An empty sequence is not allowed as the
>   second argument of fn:substring(). Found while atomizing the first
>   operand of '='

Here is my complete `xsl:accumulator`

```xml
<xsl:accumulator name="position-count" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="1" streamable="no">
       <xsl:accumulator-rule match="$MFL/MessageFormat/StructFormat" phase="end">
           <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="./@repeat = '*' ">
                   <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="substring($msg, $value, string-length(./TagField/@value)) != ./TagField/@value">
                           <xsl:sequence select="$value"/>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:variable name="repeat" select="count(tokenize(fn:substring($msg, $value) , ./TagField/@value)) - 1"/>
                           <xsl:sequence select="$value + map:get($groupsize, ./@name) * $repeat"/>
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="substring($msg, $value, string-length(./TagField/@value)) = ./TagField/@value">
                   <!--<xsl:sequence select="$value + xs:integer(sum(.//FieldFormat/@length)) + string-length(./TagField/@value)"/>-->
                   <xsl:sequence select="$value + map:get($groupsize, string(./@name))"/>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
               </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:accumulator-rule>
   </xsl:accumulator>
```

**Backgroud:**

I have to solve following problem, the input is plain text with variable length, for example

`"H0 EVU_DBSRD PVG     Z24 ABF-RF  IR                                       0112019-12-10-14.46.18.553122NJJNNJNM1           80142455360001                        M2 10.12.201914:40:00Z1 RABWR1  10.12.2019                    10.12.201914:40:00 0000R1 00133807843874880201912103988789201912101530419325346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 002338078480716                 201912101446013716142455                                   000    NN                                                R1 00324714370125580201912103961427201912101200186865346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 00433807840438580201912103984329201912101530381256346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 00524714273013180201912093997400201912090900494682346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 00637847829609880201912104006488201912101530572232346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 00737807836474280201912103954824201912101530128369346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 008338079134858                 201912101446013858142455                                   000    NN                                                R1 00933807849379280201912103979328201912101530334318346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 01037847829649480201912103990982201912101530433292346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 011338078414616                 201912101446013616142455                                   000    NN                                                "`

( I put the text in quote to keep spaces after last character N)

The expected out is following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TransportEvent>
    <TransportEventHeader>
        <NotificationTriggeringOU>EVU_DBSRD</NotificationTriggeringOU>
        <NotificationTriggeringIT>PVG</NotificationTriggeringIT>
        <NotificationReference>Z</NotificationReference>
        <NotificationCode>24</NotificationCode>
        <NotificationType>ABF-RF</NotificationType>
        <NotificationStatus>I</NotificationStatus>
        <NotificationTripType>R</NotificationTripType>
        <ProducingRailwayUndertaking/>
        <ExternalPartner>                                   </ExternalPartner>
        <ActualNumberOfWagons>11</ActualNumberOfWagons>
        <ProcessingTime>2019-12-10-14.46.18.553122</ProcessingTime>
        <NotificationFunctionalClassification>
            <OrderRelevant>N</OrderRelevant>
            <TimetableRelevant>J</TimetableRelevant>
            <CapacityRelevant>J</CapacityRelevant>
            <IntermodalRelevant>N</IntermodalRelevant>
            <XrailRelevant>N</XrailRelevant>
            <NotificationLocationRelevant>J</NotificationLocationRelevant>
        </NotificationFunctionalClassification>
        <Reserve>N</Reserve>
    </TransportEventHeader>
    <NotificationLocation>
        <CurrentLocation>
            <CurrentLocationRL100/>
            <CurrentLocationLocationType/>
            <CurrentUICRailAuthorityNumber>    80</CurrentUICRailAuthorityNumber>
            <CurrentNetworkLocationNumber>142455</CurrentNetworkLocationNumber>
            <CurrentLocationSatelliteNumber>36</CurrentLocationSatelliteNumber>
            <CurrentFreightCarLocationNumber>0001</CurrentFreightCarLocationNumber>
        </CurrentLocation>
        <NextLocation>
            <NextLocationRL100/>
            <NextLocationLocationType/>
            <NextUICRailAuthorityNumber/>
            <NextNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <NextLocationSatelliteNumber/>
            <NextFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </NextLocation>
    </NotificationLocation>
    <NotificationTime>
        <ActualTime>10.12.201914:40:00</ActualTime>
    </NotificationTime>
    <Trip>
        <TripNumber>RABWR1</TripNumber>
        <RegionDBNetz/>
        <NationalProductionDate>10.12.2019</NationalProductionDate>
        <TrainTypeMainNumber/>
        <TrainTypeSubNumber/>
        <DepartureStationRL100/>
        <DepartureStationUICRailAuthority/>
        <DepartureStationNetworkLocation/>
        <TargetTime>10.12.201914:40:00</TargetTime>
        <RelativeTime> 0000</RelativeTime>
    </Trip>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>1</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>338078438748</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey>80201912103988789</OrderingCommercialOrderKey>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101530419325346965</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>2</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>338078480716</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey/>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101446013716142455</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>3</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>247143701255</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey>80201912103961427</OrderingCommercialOrderKey>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101200186865346965</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>4</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>338078404385</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey>80201912103984329</OrderingCommercialOrderKey>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101530381256346965</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>5</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>247142730131</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey>80201912093997400</OrderingCommercialOrderKey>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912090900494682346965</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>6</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>378478296098</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey>80201912104006488</OrderingCommercialOrderKey>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101530572232346965</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>7</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>378078364742</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey>80201912103954824</OrderingCommercialOrderKey>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101530128369346965</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>8</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>338079134858</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey/>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101446013858142455</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>9</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>338078493792</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey>80201912103979328</OrderingCommercialOrderKey>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101530334318346965</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>10</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>378478296494</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey>80201912103990982</OrderingCommercialOrderKey>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101530433292346965</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
    <Ordering>
        <OrderingPosition>11</OrderingPosition>
        <OrderingVehicleNumber>338078414616</OrderingVehicleNumber>
        <OrderingCommercialOrderKey/>
        <OrderingProductionOrderKey>201912101446013616142455</OrderingProductionOrderKey>
        <OrderingConsignmentNumberID/>
        <OrderingTrainGroup>0</OrderingTrainGroup>
        <FlagActivation/>
        <FlagClosing/>
        <FlagCompletion/>
        <FlagSuspended/>
        <WagonIntermodal>N</WagonIntermodal>
        <OderIntermodal>N</OderIntermodal>
        <Activation>
            <ActivationRL100Location/>
            <ActivationLocationLocationType/>
            <ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Activation>
        <Completion>
            <CompletionRL100Location/>
            <CompletionLocationLocationType/>
            <CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionNetworkLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber/>
            <CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber/>
        </Completion>
    </Ordering>
</TransportEvent>
```

My XSLT tempalte is working with XML Spy Pro 2020 sp1, however with saxon 9.9 PE I get error with my accumulator in the accumulator-rule.

I know Saxon implementation is strict to W3C XSLT spec, XML Spy Pro usually not always. What did I wrong with my ``accumulator-rule`?

Comment: It would save everyone effort if you told us what the error was.

Comment: Sorry. I updated my post and added the error reported by Saxon. And my xslt template is in my reply, since I can't put all in one post.

Comment: I use an `accumulator` to remember the start postion of a group (`StructFormat` in the rules.xml) . Some `StructFormat` are optional, some are repeating N times. It depends on if the value `TagField/@value` occues or how many time `TagField/@value` occures. when `fn:accumulator-before` and `fn:accumulator-after`, then this `StructFormat` will be skippted.

Comment: What happens if you change the `<xsl:value-of select="$value"/>` in the `xsl:otherwise` to `<xsl:sequence select="$value"/>`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the failure, but I'm not entirely clear that I'm running the test correctly. You seem to access the input XML both as the initial context item and as the value of variable $MFL (read using the `document()` function) which seems a little curious. The `xsl:value-of` on line 49 should clearly be `xsl:sequence`, but I don't think that's the cause of the error. What happens if you declare the accumulator with `as="xs:integer"` rather than `xs:integer?`

Comment: I change it as @MartinHonnen suggested. The result is the same. It works with Altova, but not with Saxon, and the error is the same.

Comment: @MichaelKay I change  `as="xs:integer?"` to `xs:integer?`. And I got the error. The comment is limited for text input, so I couldn't paste the complete error message. But from my understanding, it's the same error.
Error evaluating (fn:accumulator-before(...) = fn:accumulator-after(...)) in xsl:sequence/@select on line 47 column 76 of format.xslt:
  XPTY0004: An empty sequence is not allowed as the @select attribute of
  xsl:accumulator-rule.

Comment: @MichaelKay You ae right, the rules.xml is read by calling `document()`.

For testing with Saxon, I call it like this:

`java -cp /d/SaxonPE9-9-1-5J/saxon9pe.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:input.xml -xsl:format.xslt  -o:output.xml`, where rules.xml and format.xslt are in the same directory, and input.xml could be any valid xml file.

Comment: @MichaelKay I found my error.  When I calculate group size. I forgot to put $MFL in my select in `<xsl:for-each select="/MessageFormat/StructFormat">`, now I change it to `<xsl:for-each select="$MFL/MessageFormat/StructFormat">`. It works now both with Saxon and Altova. I don't know why it worked before with Altova. It's a mystery for me.

Comment: The second argument of `substring()` is the start position in the first argument. I called it as `substring($msg, $value, string-length(./TagField/@value))`, and the second argument is `$value`, which has an initial value `1`. Why does Saxon complain, that $value is empty? ("An empty sequence is not allowed as the second argument of fn:substring()")
I can only see, $value is declared as `xs:integer`, however, `substring()` expects `xs:double` in the 2nd arugment.

Comment: As I say, I have not been able to reproduce the failure, therefore I cannot explain it. The code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since my post is too long, I have to add more text here:

And the rules for generating xml are specified in an XML file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<MessageFormat name='TransportEvent' version='2.02'>
    <StructFormat name='TransportEventHeader' delimOptional='n'>
        <TagField type='String' value='H0 '/>
        <FieldFormat name='NotificationTriggeringOU' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='10' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='NotificationTriggeringIT' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='8' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='NotificationReference' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='NotificationCode' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='3' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='NotificationType' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='8' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='NotificationStatus' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='NotificationTripType' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='ProducingRailwayUndertaking' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='4' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='ExternalPartner' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='35' />
        <FieldFormat name='ActualNumberOfWagons' type='Numeric' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='3' pad='0' padType='leading' trimLeading='0'/>
        <FieldFormat name='ProcessingTime' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='26' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <StructFormat name='NotificationFunctionalClassification' delimOptional='y' optional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='OrderRelevant' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='TimetableRelevant' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CapacityRelevant' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='IntermodalRelevant' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' />
            <FieldFormat name='XrailRelevant' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' />
            <FieldFormat name='NotificationLocationRelevant' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' />
        </StructFormat>
        <FieldFormat name='Reserve' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' />
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='NotificationLocation' delimOptional='n' optional='y'>
        <TagField type='String' value='M1 '/>
        <StructFormat name='CurrentLocation' delimOptional='y' optional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='CurrentLocationRL100' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='5' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CurrentLocationLocationType' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CurrentUICRailAuthorityNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CurrentNetworkLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CurrentLocationSatelliteNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='2' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CurrentFreightCarLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='4' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='NextLocation' delimOptional='y' optional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='NextLocationRL100' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='5' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='NextLocationLocationType' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='NextUICRailAuthorityNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='NextNetworkLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='NextLocationSatelliteNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='2' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='NextFreightCarLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='4' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        </StructFormat>
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='NotificationTime' delimOptional='n'>
        <TagField type='String' value='M2 '/>
        <FieldFormat name='ActualTime' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='18' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='Trip' delimOptional='n' optional='y'>
        <TagField type='String' value='Z1 '/>
        <FieldFormat name='TripNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='RegionDBNetz' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='2' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='NationalProductionDate' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='10' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='TrainTypeMainNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='2' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='TrainTypeSubNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='DepartureStationRL100' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='5' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='DepartureStationUICRailAuthority' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='DepartureStationNetworkLocation' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='TargetTime' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='18' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='RelativeTime' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='5' pad='0' padType='leading' trimTrailing=' '/>
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='HandoverTakeover' delimOptional='n' optional='y'>
        <TagField type='String' value='U1 '/>
        <FieldFormat name='HandoverTakeoverFlag' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='ConsigningRU' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='AcceptingRU' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='4' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='UICBorderCode' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='3' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='Ordering' delimOptional='n' optional='y' repeat='*'>
        <TagField type='String' value='R1 '/>
        <FieldFormat name='OrderingPosition' type='Numeric' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='3' pad='0' padType='leading' trimLeading='0'/>
        <FieldFormat name='OrderingVehicleNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='12' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='OrderingCommercialOrderKey' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='17' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='OrderingProductionOrderKey' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='24' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='OrderingConsignmentNumberID' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='35' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='OrderingTrainGroup' type='Numeric' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='3' pad='0' padType='leading' trimLeading='0'/>
        <FieldFormat name='FlagActivation' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='FlagClosing' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='FlagCompletion' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='FlagSuspended' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='WagonIntermodal' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' />
        <FieldFormat name='OderIntermodal' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' />
        <StructFormat name='Activation' delimOptional='y' optional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='ActivationRL100Location' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='5' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='ActivationLocationLocationType' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='ActivationUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='ActivationNetworkLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='ActivationSatelliteLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='2' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='ActivationFreightCarLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='4' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        </StructFormat>
        <StructFormat name='Completion' delimOptional='y' optional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='CompletionRL100Location' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='5' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CompletionLocationLocationType' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CompletionUICRailAuthorityLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CompletionNetworkLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CompletionSatelliteLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='2' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='CompletionFreightCarLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='4' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        </StructFormat>
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='Vehicle' delimOptional='n' optional='y' repeat='*'>
        <TagField type='String' value='F1 '/>
        <FieldFormat name='VehicleNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='12' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <StructFormat name='Damage' delimOptional='y' optional='y'>
            <FieldFormat name='CapabilityCode' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='HighDemandFromDate' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='10' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='LastCarInspectorTime' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='18' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='DamageTypeCode' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='3' repeat='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='DamageCauseCode' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='1' repeat='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='DamageDeploymentConstraint' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='2' repeat='3' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
            <FieldFormat name='DamageMaxSpeed' type='Numeric' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='3' pad='0' padType='leading' trimLeading='0'/>
        </StructFormat>
    </StructFormat>
    <StructFormat name='Order' delimOptional='n' optional='y' repeat='*'>
        <TagField type='String' value='A1 '/>
        <FieldFormat name='VehicleNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' length='12' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='CommercialOrderKey' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='17' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='ProductionOrderKey' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='24' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='ConsignmentNumberID' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='35' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='OrderEntrySystem' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='3' pad='  ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='TransportType' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='2' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='DispatchDate' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='10' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='DispatchNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='DestinationDispatchUICRailAuthorityNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='DestinationDispatchLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='DestinationReceptionUICRailAuthorityNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='DestinationReceptionLocationNumber' type='String' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad=' ' padType='trailing' trimTrailing=' '/>
        <FieldFormat name='FreightNetLoad' type='Numeric' delimOptional='y' optional='y' length='6' pad='0' padType='leading' trimLeading='0'/>
    </StructFormat>
</MessageFormat>
```

Here is my XSLT template.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:csb="http://www.dbcargo.org/csb" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">
    <xsl:param name="msg" as="xs:string">H0 EVU_DBSRD PVG     Z24 ABF-RF  IR                                       0112019-12-10-14.46.18.553122NJJNNJNM1           80142455360001                        M2 10.12.201914:40:00Z1 RABWR1  10.12.2019                    10.12.201914:40:00 0000R1 00133807843874880201912103988789201912101530419325346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 002338078480716                 201912101446013716142455                                   000    NN                                                R1 00324714370125580201912103961427201912101200186865346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 00433807840438580201912103984329201912101530381256346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 00524714273013180201912093997400201912090900494682346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 00637847829609880201912104006488201912101530572232346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 00737807836474280201912103954824201912101530128369346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 008338079134858                 201912101446013858142455                                   000    NN                                                R1 00933807849379280201912103979328201912101530334318346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 01037847829649480201912103990982201912101530433292346965                                   000    NN                                                R1 011338078414616                 201912101446013616142455                                   000    NN                                                </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="relatviePath2MFL" as="xs:string" select="'./rules.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="MFL" select="document($relatviePath2MFL)"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:mode name="unroll" on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="position-count"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="minimalBeginOfRepeatGroup" as="xs:integer" select="fn:string-length($msg) - sum(/MessageFormat/StructFormat[not(@optional='y')]//FieldFormat/@length) + string-length( string-join(/MessageFormat/StructFormat[not(@optional='y')]//TagField/@value))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="groupsize" as="map(xs:string, xs:integer)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:for-each select="/MessageFormat/StructFormat">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- there are FieldFormat with repeat attribute -->
                    <xsl:when test=".//FieldFormat[@repeat]">
                        <xsl:variable name="sum1" select="xs:integer( sum(.//FieldFormat[not(@repeat)]/@length))"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="sum2" select="xs:integer( sum(for-each(.//FieldFormat[@repeat], function ($arg) as xs:integer {xs:integer($arg/@length) * xs:integer($arg/@repeat)})))"/>
                        <xsl:map-entry key="string(./@name)">
                            <xsl:sequence select="xs:integer( $sum1 + $sum2 + string-length(./TagField/@value))"/>
                        </xsl:map-entry>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:map-entry key="string(./@name)">
                            <xsl:sequence select="xs:integer( sum(.//FieldFormat/@length)) + string-length(./TagField/@value)"/>
                        </xsl:map-entry>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:accumulator name="position-count" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="1" streamable="no">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="$MFL/MessageFormat/StructFormat" phase="end">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./@repeat = '*' ">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="substring($msg, $value, string-length(./TagField/@value)) != ./TagField/@value">
                            <xsl:sequence select="$value"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:variable name="repeat" select="count(tokenize(fn:substring($msg, $value) , ./TagField/@value)) - 1"/>
                            <xsl:sequence select="$value + map:get($groupsize, ./@name) * $repeat"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="substring($msg, $value, string-length(./TagField/@value)) = ./TagField/@value">
                    <xsl:sequence select="$value + map:get($groupsize, string(./@name))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:accumulator-rule>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    <xsl:template match="StructFormat[@repeat]" mode="unroll">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$this/@repeat != '*' ">
                <xsl:for-each select="1 to @repeat">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$this/@delimOptional = 'n' and $this/TagField and contains($msg, $this/TagField)">
                            <xsl:copy select="$this">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise/>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="groupMsg" select="fn:substring($msg, fn:accumulator-before('position-count'), fn:accumulator-after('position-count'))"/>
                <xsl:variable name="repeat" select="count(tokenize($groupMsg, $this/TagField/@value)) - 1"/>
                <xsl:comment select="$repeat"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="1 to $repeat">
                    <xsl:copy select="$this">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="$MFL/MessageFormat/StructFormat[not(@repeat) and TagField]" mode="unroll">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="fn:accumulator-before('position-count') = fn:accumulator-after('position-count')"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy select="$this">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FieldFormat[@repeat]" mode="unroll">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to @repeat">
            <xsl:copy select="$this">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @repeat, node()" mode="#current"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="complete-struct">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$MFL/*" mode="unroll"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="group">
            <output>
                <xsl:for-each select="$MFL/MessageFormat/StructFormat">
                    <xsl:if test="fn:accumulator-before('position-count') != fn:accumulator-after('position-count')">
                        <xsl:element name="{./@name}">
                            <xsl:attribute name="start" select="fn:accumulator-before('position-count')"/>
                            <xsl:attribute name="length" select="fn:accumulator-after('position-count')-1"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </output>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$MFL/MessageFormat/@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$complete-struct/*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="StructFormat">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FieldFormat">
        <xsl:variable name="precedingFieldFormatsLength" select="sum(preceding::FieldFormat/@length)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="offset">
            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(string-join(./preceding::TagField/@value, ''))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:variable name="value" select="substring($msg, 1 + $precedingFieldFormatsLength + $offset, @length)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="csb:formatField(.,$value)"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- format output -->
    <xsl:function name="csb:formatField" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="field" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$field/@length = '1' and $value = ' '">
                <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- remove leading and trailing space -->
            <xsl:when test="$field/@trimLeading = ' ' and $field/@trimTrailing = ' '">
                <xsl:value-of select="fn:replace($value, '^\s+|\s+$', '')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- remove ONLY leading space -->
            <xsl:when test="$field/@trimLeading = ' '  and fn:not(fn:exists($field//@trimTrailing))">
                <xsl:value-of select="fn:replace($value, '^\s+', '')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- remove ONLY trailing space -->
            <xsl:when test="$field/@trimTrailing = ' '  and fn:not(fn:exists($field//@trimLeading))">
                <xsl:value-of select="fn:replace($value, '\s+$', '')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- remove leading 0 -->
            <xsl:when test="$field/@type = 'Numeric'  and $field/@trimLeading = '0'  and fn:not(fn:exists($field//@trimTrailing))">
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="fn:replace($value, '^0+', '')"/> -->
                <xsl:if test="number($value) != number($value)">
                    <!-- validate data -->
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Transformation failed. The field', $field, ' has invalid value')"/>
                    </xsl:message>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="number($value)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```